# namespaces and specific xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, nant, xmlpoke

Can anyone tell me how can I get the xpath of the name attribute from this file:

```
<asmv1:assembly xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity name="MyName"/>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

I'm trying to get it for nant xmlpoke task without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
//asmv1:assembly/asmv1:assemblyIdentity/@name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this XPath

```
/*[local-name()='assembly']/assemblyIdentity/@name
```